# Why is jQuery fadeIn() not working properly?

Tags: jquery, settimeout, fadein

I have this function that I wrote that is supposed to display notifications:

```
function newNotification(message) {
    window.clearTimeout(window.tid);
    $("#notify").stop().prepend(message + '<br/>').fadeIn(400, function() {
        window.tid = window.setTimeout(function() {
            $("#notify").fadeOut('3000', function() {
               $("#notify").html('');
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

The problem is that if I pass a notification while another is fading out the `#notify` div doesn't fade back in. Its opacity gets stuck between 0 and 1.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: have you tried to clear the queue using: `.stop(1)` or also with a `jump-to end` like: `.stop(1,1)` ?

Comment: Why do you have a .stop() in your entire function? It's probably that part that's pausing the animations when you pass in another notification.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan .stop(1) does not work and stop(1,1) doesn't do what I need. I need the animation to stop where it is and continue fading in from there.

Comment: @RenoYeo .stop() is there to stop the .fadeOut() animation from inside the setTimeout().

Comment: @Soso Ok, I think I know what the problem is. I'm creating a test case. I'll post an answer soon!

Comment: remove the quotes wherever you are using numbers. [in your code, fadeOut('3000'...);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I finally managed to figure it out. `FadeIn()` only works if the element is hidden, that's why it gets stuck when the opacity is between 0 and 1.

I just had to replace `FadeIn()` with `FadeTo()` to make it work.

Thanks for your help everyone!